# master failed to start, check stderr log for details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, unicorn

I'm trying to start unicorn and I keep getting this error constantly.

My unicorn.rb (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d1f3d9bcdd1a6c4d8435)

Command that I'm using to start unicorn:

`/home/app/adsgold/# unicorn_rails master -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E production`

Commands that I've already tried:

`/home/app/adsgold/# unicorn_rails -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E production`

`/home/app/adsgold/# unicorn_rails master -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E production -p 3000`

`/home/app/adsgold/# bundle exec master unicorn -c unicorn.cnf -E production -D`

Complete error beeing shown: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/828d9677f928fa671762

Answer (score 6):

It looks you have RVM and Ruby installed system-wide. Generally it may cause lots of issues. Even RVM documentation [warns about that](http://rvm.io/rvm/install#installation-explained). Try to install RVM and Ruby as user, which owns `app` directory. In that case you will get consistent system.

By the way, do you have this directory `/home/deploy/apps/shared` on your environment? Is it writable for your App? According Unicorn **config** following things depend on it:

```
pid "/home/deploy/apps/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/home/deploy/apps/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "/home/deploy/apps/shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
```

If you do have all this stuff, content of `/home/deploy/apps/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log` also would be helpful.

Comment: I checked permissions between the older server and the new server and both are exactly the same. Here is the last 200 lines of "unicorn.stderr.log" https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b9bbb8622958ab80717

Comment: Any ideas? I'm just can't understand why is it not working as it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Are the necessary permissions in place? (I notice the read error comes from a globally-installed gem, so I'm wondering what all is where.)

Comment: I migrated from a dedicated server to this one. It is a exact perfect image of the old server. The old one is still kicking and responding well with the same permissions this one have. Which location should I look for correct permissions if that might be the case?